# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen auf Wunsch und bei Wunsch?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, preposition

Ist die Variante `bei Wunsch` überhaupt richtig? Und wenn ja was ist der Unterschied zwischen `bei Wunsch` und `auf Wunsch` ?

Answer (score 1):

Es wird etwas **auf** Wunsch von jemandem getan (diese Person wird konkret bennant):

> **Auf Wunsch** *des Vorstandes* wurde die Produktivität erhöht.

> Die Nase wurde **auf Wunsch** *des Patienten* verändert.

---

Es wird etwas **bei** dem **Wunsch** von jemandem getan(Diese Person wird nicht direkt genannt):

> (...) ,besonders **bei Wunsch** für vollständige Wiederherstellung des Friedens.

> Aus ärztlicher Sicht ist **bei Wunsch** nach Sektio ohne Indikation ein eingehendes Beratungsgespräch in der Schwangerschaft angezeigt.

---

Ein Beispiel von mir, das den Unterschied (vielleicht) verdeutlicht:

> **Bei Wunsch** nach Vergeltung soll ich **auf Wunsch** meines Königs in die Schlacht ziehen.

Comment: Was wäre dann in den folgenden Beispielen richtig: bei/auf Wunsch kann ein Termin vereinbart werden, bei/auf Wunsch kann das Möbel übernommen werden ?

Comment: @Nn9Ich sehe bei den Beispielen keinen besonders großen Unterschied. Ich persönlich würde `Auf Wunsch`kann ein Termin vereinbart werden." und "'`Auf Wunsch` kann das Möbel übernommen werden" bevorzugen.

Comment: okay, danke sehr :)

Comment: Ich vermute, dass das vielleicht regional unterschiedlich ist, aber für mich (gelebt in Norddeutschland, Baden und im Rheinland) klingt "bei Wunsch" ungewohnt, ich würde das sehr selten oder gar nicht benutzen. Das Beispiel "Aus ärztlicher Sicht..." ist das einzige, das ich nachvollziehen kann. "Bei Wunsch für..." klingt für mich völlig falsch, es wäre, wenn überhaupt, immer "Bei Wunsch nach..". "Auf Wunsch" ist dagegen eine alltägliche Formulierung. In den "Bei Wunsch"-Beispielen würde ich eigentlich immer "Bei einem Wunsch..." o.ä. sagen.

Comment: Die einzigen beiden Sätze, die keine Zitate darstellen, sind etwas dünn. Ohne zusätzliche Erklärung sehen ich keinen nennenswerten Nutzen in der Antwort.

Comment: @guidot Jetzt wo ich das nochmal lese denke ich, dass du Recht hast. Ich habe in meinen letzten Absatz wohl etwas viel hereininterpretiert..

Answer (score 1):

*Bei Wunsch* heißt so viel wie: *falls der Wunsch geäußert wird*. Beispiel:

> Bei Wunsch auf Mietminderung sind Nachweise der Meldung an den Vermieter zu erbringen.

*Auf Wunsch + Genitiv* bezeichnet die Person, die den Wunsch äußert.

> Auf Wunsch des Mitarbeiters wurde eine Versetzung angestoßen.